# discord.py error missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'

Tags: python, pycharm, discord.py

I was trying to make a quick bot for discord and I used this code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='0')

@bot.command(name='ping')
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Pong!')

bot.run('MY_DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN')
```

And i get this error:

```
BotBase.__init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'
```

I'm not sure what argument it is missing beacause I've encountered an error like this

Answer (score 2):

You have to enable the intents from the dev portal and then call those intents

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.message_content = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="0", intents=intents, case_insensitive=True)

@bot.command(name='ping')
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Pong!')

bot.run('YOUR_DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN')
```

Intents doc - https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html